# How to import complex .txt file to matrix in MMA for user defined keywords / database?

Tags: matrix, export, import, text

I am thinking about how can we import complex .txt file (Ansys/Abaqus) to MMA for the selected database?

For example: **txt file (input file)**:

```
 ...
 ...
 10894, 10895, 10896, 10897, 10898, 10899, 10900, 10901, 10902, 10903, 10904, 10905, 10906, 10907, 10908, 10909
 10910, 10911, 10912, 10913, 10914, 10915, 10916, 10917, 10918, 10919, 10920, 10921, 10922, 10923, 10924, 10925
 10926, 10927
*Edfsf, cadifd=Saoot-23, coming
 10122,  10534,      1
*Gaaf, nlau=Saoot-24
   29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34,  400,  401,  402,  403,  404,  405,  406,  407,  408,  409
  410,  411,  412,  413,  414,  415,  416,  439,  440,  441,  442,  443,  444,  445,  446,  447
 3157, 3158, 3159, 3160, 3161, 3162, 3163, 3164, 3165, 3166, 3167, 3168, 3169, 3170, 3171, 3172
 3173, 3174, 3175, 3176, 3177, 3178
*Edfsf, cadifd=Saoot-24, coming
 1477,  1782,     1
*Gaaf, nlau=Saoot-25
   32,   33,   76,   86,  455,  456,  457,  458,  459,  460,  461,  462,  463,  464,  465,  466
 9611, 9612, 9613, 9614, 9615, 9616, 9617, 9618, 9619, 9620, 9621, 9622, 9623, 9624, 9625, 9626
 9627, 9628, 9629, 9630
*Edfsf, cadifd=Saoot-25, coming
 8891,  9060,     1
*Gaaf, nlau=Saoot-26
   24,   25,   28,   29,   30,  344,  345,  346,  347,  348,  349,  350,  351,  352,  353,  354
  355,  356,  387,  388,  389,  390,  391,  392,  393,  394,  395,  396,  397,  398,  399,  400  
 ...
 ...
```

What do we need is such kind of **output in MMA (matrix)**:

```
10122 10534 23
1477 1782 24
8891 9060 25
```

Import rule is: we find ***Edfsf** line: the value after the key words **Saoot-** and the following line two values: namely **10122 10534 23**
then we repeat the rule for the next same key words.

Sure, if I import all the data in MMA, it is ok, but how to import selected information in MMA, at least not clear for me now.

Thanks a lot for your support in advance

Comment: Is importing the entire file and then processing it acceptable or does the solution have to read the file line by line and filter/construct the required output?

Comment: Where does this file come from? Can you add some background information?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, the second option:the solution have to read the file line by line and filter/construct the required output.

Comment: @xzczd , abaqus/ansys/codeaster and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to export a more regular file (say, a binary file arranged according to a certain template) from these softwares?

Comment: @xzczd  , original file is large, method is how  to get the used defined database from original file in MMA.

Comment: I mean, can a easier-to-analyse file be exported from these softwares? Or you have to live with this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86012/discussion-between-abcdemmm-and-xzczd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about abaqus/ansys/codeaster, but I suspect the .txt file illustrated in the question isn't the best choice for exporting data from these softwares. Anyway, the following is a possible solution if you have to live with the .txt file:

```
read[stream_] := 
 Last@Last@Reap@(While[True, 
      Sow@{StringCases[If[# === EndOfFile, Break[], #] &@Find[stream, {"Edfsf"}], 
          "Saoot-" ~~ a__ ~~ "," :> ToExpression@a][[1]], 
        Read[stream, Number],
        Skip[stream, Word]; Read[stream, Number]}]; Close[stream])
```

The input of `read` function is a stream, which you can create with `OpenRead` function in your real case. Here I'll simply illustrate with `StringToStream`:

```
string = "*Edfsf, cadifd=Saoot-23, coming
   10122,  10534,      1
  *Gaaf, nlau=Saoot-24
     29,   30,   31,   32,   33,   34,  400,  401,  402,  403,  404,  405,  406,  407,  \
408,  409
    410,  411,  412,  413,  414,  415,  416,  439,  440,  441,  442,  443,  444,  445,  \
446,  447
   3157, 3158, 3159, 3160, 3161, 3162, 3163, 3164, 3165, 3166, 3167, 3168, 3169, 3170, \
3171, 3172
   3173, 3174, 3175, 3176, 3177, 3178
  *Edfsf, cadifd=Saoot-24, coming
   1477,  1782,     1
  *Gaaf, nlau=Saoot-25
     32,   33,   76,   86,  455,  456,  457,  458,  459,  460,  461,  462,  463,  464,  \
465,  466
   9611, 9612, 9613, 9614, 9615, 9616, 9617, 9618, 9619, 9620, 9621, 9622, 9623, 9624, \
9625, 9626
   9627, 9628, 9629, 9630
  *Edfsf, cadifd=Saoot-25, coming
   8891,  9060,     1";

stream = StringToStream@string;

read@stream
(* {{23, 10122, 10534}, {24, 1477, 1782}, {25, 8891, 9060}} *)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! however, "string =  " this method can not be used  for very large data (more than 5000 lines), can we use txt or other files to do this work?

Comment: "string = "xxx.txt""???

Comment: @ABCDEMMM As mentioned above, please check the document of `OpenRead`.

Comment: thanks! str = OpenRead["test.txt"] ;string = "str"; this method doesnot work!

Comment: @ABCDEMMM It should be `read@str`. If you still don't understand, remove all the `;` and observe those outputs, and think about what input should be used for `read`, and finally, don't forget to check the document by pressing **F1**.

Comment: after str = OpenRead["test.txt"] , then StringToStream@str; then read@str ?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM `str = OpenRead["test.txt"]; read@str`. Notice `OpenRead` will create a `InputStream[…]`, just like `StringToStream`. Once again, please  carefully check the documents of all the functions that you don't understand. (Including those under the **Details** section. ) Don't guess the usage of built-in functions blindly.